# Entity Framework 7 Invalid Cast

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In EF6 I had a pretty simple query:

```
_dbContext.Times.Where(t => t.UserId == userId).Sum(t => (decimal?)t.Minutes / 60m) ?? 0;
```

It just gets the total minutes for a user and divides by 60 to get the decimal hours, if there are no records for the user it returns 0.

In EF7, I get exception:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

```
InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.QueryMethodProvider.GetResult[TResult](IEnumerable`1 valueBuffers)
```

Surely this is too simple to be a bug. What's changed in EF7 - what's the correct way of doing this query?

Comment: No, internal crashes in EF always are bugs. Report this.

Comment: Issue logged at https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4308